# Create A new DATE field from Existing Short Text Field in MS ACCESS using Append Query

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have an MS ACCESS employee database.

It contains 1550 records and there are around 7 date fields, however the field types are Short Text.

The value of all these 7 date fields for the 1550 records are entered as yyyymmdd (e.g. 19870220). They are not of Date/Time field yet.

I would like to either change all these 7 fields for the 1550 records to date fields and the format them as "MM/DD/YYYY".

1. I've created Update query and also added new fields that are Date/time fields, and used CDATE function like this UptateTO: CDATE([Birthdate]), but I got error.
2. I used the Append query, also I got error.

Somehow, CDATE() function is not converting the value of the text field to date.

I'm using ACCESS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression to update your new date field:

```
Set TrueBirthDate = CDate(Format([BirthDate], "@@@@/@@/@@"))
```

The values carries no format. For display, you can set this in the Format property of the field, or the default format from your Windows settings will be used.